# Reducing Poisson Sum expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, summation-method

I am trying to reduce and obtain a simple expression from following sum

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over i}\,
{\,\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}\,\lambda^{i} \over i!}\,
{1 \over 1 - \,\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}\,}
$$

Problem can be put in general form as:

$$
\sum_{i = c}^{\infty}{1 \over i}\,
{\,\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}\,\lambda^{i} \over
i!\left(\displaystyle{\, 1 - \sum_{k = 1}^{c - 1}
{\,\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}\,\lambda^{k} \over k!}\,}\right)}\,,
\qquad  c \geq 1
$$

Comment: Are you certain the first one is what you meant to ask? It is *not* a special case of the second, at least at first glance (see the first paragraph of my answer).

Comment: I forgot the denominators ($\frac{1}{1 - e^{-\lambda}} $) in the first and second ($\sum_{k=1}^{c-1}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k} }{k!}$)question.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the "true" statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sum is
$$
e^{-\lambda}\int_0^\lambda\frac{e^x-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which is not an elementary function. However, we can use the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Convergent_series) to get
$$
e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k}{k\,k!}=e^{-\lambda}\left(\mathrm{Ei}(\lambda)-\gamma-\log\left|\lambda\right|\right)
$$